# Determine the right server for a sub-domain using a proxy/loadbalancer

Tags: nginx, google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, nginx-reverse-proxy, gcp-load-balancer

Let's take the `domain.tld` domain as an example.
I want to set up a wildcard such as `*.domain.tld`, which points to an NGINX server used as a proxy or a loadbalancer (if the GCP loadbalancer can do this).
There are several servers around the world (e.g. `srv-europe`, `srv-america`, `srv-asia`, etc.).
An application on these servers enables content to be put online on a sub-domain using a particular protocol.
The nearest server is selected using a loadbalancer.

Let's imagine that a user has created `hello.domain.tld` on `srv-america`.
How can we implement a setup using an NGINX proxy and/or a GCP loadbalancer, so that when a user goes to `hello.domain.tld` the proxy or loadbalancer must be able to determine which server it should send the request to.
So there must be a system for checking whether `hello.domain.tld` is available on one of the servers.
Does GCP or just NGINX offer a solution?

With NGINX I get the subdomain, but I don't know how to get it to test which server the data is on.

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    '' close;
}

server {
    server_name ~^(?<subdomain>.+)\.domain.tld$;
    listen 80;

    listen 443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/certs/domain.tld.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/certs/domain.tld.key;

    error_page 502 /nosubdomain.txt;
    location = /nosubdomain.txt {
                return 200 "No website here.";
                internal;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_read_timeout 600s;
        proxy_send_timeout 600s;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_pass ???;
    }

    server_tokens off;
}
```

Also, can a GCP service do this directly without using a NGINX proxy?

Comment: Your design is flawed. 1) You cannot use a wild card for Google-managed certificates. You can issue one yourself and load it into the load balancer. 2) Do not use separate domain names for geographies. Instead, use a load balancer, Managed Instance Groups, and put a group in each desired geolocation. 3) You still want Nginx or similar on each server.